# Using a for loop to count size or List<string>?

Tags: java

I have a for loop in which i test for the size of a list.

```
for(int i = 0; i< thumbLinks.size(); i++) {
                        Log.e("URL" + i, thumbLinks.get(i));




                 url0 = thumbLinks.get(i);
                 url1 = thumbLinks.get(i); 

                 //Fix index out of bounds exception
                 url2 = thumbLinks.get(i);



              }
```

When i is added each time as you can see i am asking for i 3 times to get 3 urls. Since i am unsure about how many URL's i will have. I use i to increase.
The correct output i want is for

```
    url0 = thumbLinks.get(i);// which is support to be equivalent to 1
    url1 = thunkLinks.get(i);//which is suppose to be equivalent to 2
```

and so on..

But my code doesnt do this...

It just adds 1 each time to each url.
How can i fix this
?

Comment: Let me undestand, what you want is to take when i==1 the value in url1, when i==2 the value in url2 and so on?

Comment: url0, ur1 and url2 are the SAME. i only gets incremented for each loop of the block within the braces

Comment: So, you would like to get the last 3 urls from that list ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, so it sounds like you *really* only want to deal with *up to* three URLs. So you want something like:

```
String url0 = thumbLinks.size() > 0 ? thumbLinks.get(0) : null;
String url1 = thumbLinks.size() > 1 ? thumbLinks.get(1) : null;
String url2 = thumbLinks.size() > 2 ? thumbLinks.get(2) : null;

// Use url0, url1 and url2 where any or all of them may be null
```

EDIT: I'm assuming you want to deal with the URLs in batches of three for some reason. If that's not the case, it's not clear what you *are* trying to do.

Your code isn't clear - you're not incrementing `i` between calls to `thumbLinks.get(i)` - but I suspect you want something like:

```
if (thumbLinks.size() % 3 != 0) {
   // What do you want to do if it's not a multiple of three?
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
}
for (int i = 0; i < thumbLinks.size(); i += 3) {
    String url0 = thumbLinks.get(i);
    String url1 = thumbLinks.get(i + 1);
    String url2 = thumbLinks.get(i + 2);
    // Use url0, url1 and url2
}
```

Or:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < thumbLinks.size() - 2; i += 3) {
    String url0 = thumbLinks.get(i);
    String url1 = thumbLinks.get(i + 1);
    String url2 = thumbLinks.get(i + 2);
    // Use url0, url1 and url2
}
for (; i < thumbLinks.size(); i++) {
  // Deal with the trailing URLs here, one at a time...
}
```

Comment: I agree, in the code you've pasted, the value of i is always the same for each call to get(i). That's why you get the same value.

Comment: @Jokahero: I've tried to provide the code the OP probably *wants* rather than the broken code he's currently *got*.

Comment: Your last code example is what i want to do. I want i to equal the correct URL in the thumbLinks list each time the url0,url1,url2 looks for each get.(i).

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: I'm afraid you're still not communicating what you're trying to do very well - are you trying to deal with 3 URLs at a time or not?

Comment: ALso if their are more than three urls the 4th one and so on i want to leave out.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes I understood, my comment just tried to add an explanation about the fact that the value of i was always the same. I should have add the @ tag or comment directly the question :s

Comment: Correct im dealing with 3 url's at a time..supposedly..The thing is when i am parsing my html i dont know exactly how many url's i will get it suppose to be 3 but sometimes it can be less or more, if its more i just want to get 3 strings. thats it...if its less i shouldnt be calling to get 3 url's when only 2 exist. This will cause indexOutOfBounds error

Comment: @coder_For_Life2: Okay, so you don't actually want to go through the whole list to start with. I wish you'd explained all this to start with - please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Is your book good? i need a good c# book. And what are the best java books?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: Well *I* think my book is good :) But it's not really for newcomers to C# - it assumes a fair amount of C# experience to start with. Same for Java - it depends what level you're at. I think Effective Java is one of the best books around, but that's really when you already know the language reasonably well.

Comment: Well i think i know java reasonably well. Im actually in a book right now using objective c. And i have effective java. Im going to begin reading soon as i get time. Dont want to overwhelm myself.lol

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String[] url=new String[thumbLinks.size()];
for(int i = 0; i< thumbLinks.size(); i++) 
{
Log.e("URL" + i, thumbLinks.get(i));
url[i]=thumbLinks.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have a dynamic variable within your for loop, this is *bad* code design**. You can have a dynamic value in the first section e.g.

```
 for(x = getsomedymicvalue(); x > 0; x--)
 { .. }
```

but having one in the second section is dangerous, can cause exceptions to be thrown (if they change during the loop) and should be avoided when possible.